# chat UDP client/server program

Tags: java, client-server

Hi there I'm trying to create a client/server chat program.
i have three clients and one server, when a client sends some string to the server the server will send this string to the other clients.
I have created the part where the client sends data to the server but I don't know how to send received data from a client to the other clients.

this is the code I created :

For server:

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;



public class Server {

    private static DatagramSocket serverSocket;

    public Server() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(1111);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        while(true)
           {
              DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
              serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
              String s = new String( receivePacket.getData());
              System.out.println("Client dit : " + s);
              InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
              boolean found = false;
              int port = receivePacket.getPort();
              sendData = s.getBytes();
           }

    }

}
```

for clients: (X is the number of client : client1/client2...)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


    public class ClientX {

      public ClientX() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      }

      /**
       * @param args
       * @throws IOException 
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader inFromUser =
                 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
              DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
              InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
              System.out.println("Connécté au serveur !");
              byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
              byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
              System.out.print("Ecrire un message: ");
              String s = inFromUser.readLine();
              sendData = s.getBytes();
              DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 1111);
              clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
              DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
              clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
              String message = new String(receivePacket.getData());
              System.out.println(message);
              clientSocket.close();

      }

    }
```

Comment: With UDP, you'll have to have a Server->Server relationship because UDP is not bidirectional. Of course you can hack it with [hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching), but you don't specify why you can't use the more appropriate TCP.

Comment: There is no actual question here.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear how exactly your chat should work.
But the simplest idea just to move forward is:

1. Your server should keep the latest number (X) of messages received. It would be also good to store the time each message was received.
2. Every time a client connects to the server, the server sends it the X latest messages.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the clients addresses in the server when they connect to it, then, every time a client sends a new message to the server, send that message to the other clients.

You could also use multicast. Make the clients join a multicast address, and send the new messages to that address from the server. That way you don't need to save addresses and every client can "ear" the messages.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html and http://staff.www.ltu.se/~peppar/java/multicast_example/

Comment: In addition if you are using Multicast you should know that its only for hosts on your LAN.

Comment: @OfirAttia That's not correct. It works between any two hosts provided all routers in between permit it.